# GoDaddy wordpress mail smtp with aws lightsail - error failed to connected to server

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, email, smtp

I build wordpress website with aws lightsail hosting.

I bought my domain in GoDaddy and created custom email with the domain (info@**myDomain**.com) - **myDomain** is just for the explanation.

I'm trying to configure contact form and send emails to this email.

so what I did is installed WP Mail SMTP and configure the settings.
into settings what I set is
[image]

then in SMTP Host I added
[image]

I saved the settings and send email test - I'm getting the error

> There was a problem while sending the test email.

[image]

```
Versions:
WordPress: 5.8.2
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.4.25
WP Mail SMTP: 3.2.1

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Host: relay-hosting.secureserver.net
Port: 25
SMTPSecure: string(0) ""
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(false)
SMTPAuth: bool(false)

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019

Debug:
Email Source: WP Mail SMTP
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

SMTP Debug:
2022-01-05 09:27:56 Connection: opening to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:25, timeout=300, options=array()

2022-01-05 09:28:27 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:25 (Connection timed out) [/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php line 388]

2022-01-05 09:28:27 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I tried more different smtp hosts:

1. smtpout.secureserver.net with port 465/587
2. https://email.secureserver.net
3. **myDomain**-com.mail.protection.outlook.com

nothing helped - I get the same error.

in GoDaddy I found this for my domain
[image]

I talked with GoDaddy customer service for over then 3 hours- they didn't know how to help me.
I read some tutorials such as:

https://il.godaddy.com/en/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953

I still looking for any answer.
how to configure the right SMTP with those services GoDaddy - wordpress - Aws Lightsail?

Comment: Have you tried this plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/
it will fix your SMTP issue once you configure it.

Answer (score 0):

From [Remove port 25 restriction from your Lightsail instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-port-25-throttle/):

> By default, AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25 on all Lightsail instances. To send outbound traffic on port 25, request that this restriction be removed.

You will need to request for the restriction to be removed.

Alternatively, connect to an SMTP server via a different port (which is common when using TLS).

Comment: Hey John, thanks for response. I tried your advice, what I did is, remove port 25 and save settings - it's throws an error that settings not configure in right way.. I tried also to change smtp port to 465/587 or change smtp host to any different by the list I added but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As Lightsail blocks outbound traffic on port 25. tried port number 2525.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).